# When should I use Charge-Charge Interactions, Charge-Dipole Interactions, and Dipole-Dipole Interactions in molecular simulation?

Tags: monte-carlo, atomistic-simulation, electrostatic

I used LJ-potential, Hard-sphere, Soft-sphere, Harmonic, Square-well, etc. potentials in the case of simulation of polymer movement. However, I never used

1. Charge-Charge Interactions
2. Charge-Dipole Interactions
3. Dipole-Dipole Interactions

When should I use them? I.e., to simulate what?

Are they even relevant in polymer simulation?

Comment: Did the provided answer sufficiently answer the question? If yes, kindly indicate so.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you are trying to study the formation of hydration shells around ions or something like Antifreeze Glycoproteins (AFGPs). In such cases, it is important that you include charge-dipole and dipole-dipole interactions. Previous studies have shown that classical additive FFs are not entirely suitable for such studies.

References:

1. [Influence of Polarization on Carbohydrate Hydration: A Comparative Study Using Additive and Polarizable Force Fields](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpcb.6b05546)
2. [Impact of Polarization on the Ring Puckering Dynamics of Hexose Monosaccharides](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acs.jcim.2c01286)
3. [Capturing charge and size effects of ions at the graphene–electrolyte interface using polarizable force field simulations](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2023/na/d2na00733a)